# Transforming a vector in a one of predetermined length in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am asking for an help to write the following piece of Matlab code in a faster way. The code is doing the following

(1) Consider a natural number `n` and a column vector `A` of dimension `mx1`.

(2) If `m>n` keep only the first `n` elements of `A`

(3) Otherwise add final zeros to `A` to get an `nx1` vector

My attempt is this:

```
n=4;
A=[1 2 3 4 5]'
if size(A,1)>n
        A=A(1:n); %keep only the first n elements
    else
        A=[A; zeros(size(n-size(A,1)),1)]; %add zeros to get n elements
end
```

Do you know faster ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following alternative, but at best the speed-up would be barely noticeable (and results would vary slightly, depending on `m` and `n`). Hard to imagine this being a bottleneck - most likely improving some other part of your code would produce a much more significant benefit.

```
B = zeros(n,1);
B(1:min(n,length(A))) = A(1:min(n,length(A)));
```